# postgresql bgworker SIGTERM handler called twice

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, sigterm

Im using postgresql 10.1 on Mac.

I have a trouble in terminating a background worker using SIGTERM.
In my project, im creating a new background worker using **RegisterBackgroundWorker().** 
i have included a test_function, as a signal handler for SIGTERM.
No other signal handlers are defined.

> pqsignal(SIGTERM, test_function)

when i issue `pkill -15 postgres`, i see that the handler is being called twice. Why does it happen? Am i missing anything??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use PID of the postmaster instead of postgres because this will issue SIGTERM to all the process with that name which will include your BackgroundWorker

```
kill postmaster-pid
```

will do it.